# unknown property method: 'wait' on EC2 windows server Instance

Tags: ruby

I am running ruby script  via terminal on windows instance “Windows Server 2012 R2” but facing error I.e.
“unknown property or method: `Wait'
          HRESULT error code:0x80020006
            Unknown name. (NoMethodError) “

Where as the same script is working on my windows machine. Note: Ruby version, DevKit, Gems, Ruby code & mode of execution is same for both PC’s(i.e mine & EC2 WIN instance).

Only difference is, EC2 is a windows server and mine not. Please help me out in resolving above issue.